# Entity Framework: Load data from different tables in one query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In my C# project with EF Core 5.0, I have several independents tables: `Clothes`, `Hairs`, `Makeup`. Some of their columns are similar, but some are not..`
I need to write a method that will load the rows from these tables. What I have now is:

```cs
public async Task<(ClothesDbModel[] clothes, MakeupDbModel[] makeups, HairDbModel[] hairs)> GetDressup(int[] clothesIds, int[] makeupIds, int[] hairIds)
{
    ClothesDbModel[] clothes = new ClothesDbModel[0];
    if (clothesIds.Length > 0)
    {
        clothes = await _dbContext.Clothes.Where(c => clothesIds.Contains(c.Id)).ToArrayAsync();
    }

    MakeupDbModel[] makeups = new MakeupDbModel[0];
    if (makeupIds.Length > 0)
    {
        makeups = await _dbContext.Makeups.Where(c => makeupIds.Contains(c.Id)).ToArrayAsync();
    }

    HairDbModel[] hairs = new HairDbModel[0];
    if (hairIds.Length > 0)
    {
        hairs = await _dbContext.Hairs.Where(c => hairIds.Contains(c.Id)).ToArrayAsync();
    }

    return (clothes, makeups, hairs);
}
```

However, in this case, I have 3 separate queries to the database (3 awaits). I believe that is not the best way to load the data from a performance point of view. Maybe I can load the same data using DbContext only once&

Comment: If these tables do not depend on each other, then there is no other way

Comment: As you might know EF doesn't support [multiple parallel operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/async). You _could_ create three different `_dbContext`. However, with the overhead it might not be worth it.

Comment: Actually it is possible to do that with `Concat` but it will need post-processing on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work with EF. But I know there are problems with Concat, so it may fail.

```cs
class CombinedResult
{
    public ClothesDbModel Clothes;
    public MakeupDbModel Makeup;
    public HairDbModel Hair;
}

...

public async Task<(ClothesDbModel[] clothes, MakeupDbModel[] makeups, HairDbModel[] hairs)> GetDressup(int[] clothesIds, int[] makeupIds, int[] hairIds)
{
    var queries = new List<IQueryable<CombinedResult>>();

    if (clothesIds.Length > 0)
    {
        queries.Add(_dbContext.Clothes.Where(c => clothesIds.Contains(c.Id)).Select(c => new CombinedResult { Clothes = c }));
    }

    if (makeupIds.Length > 0)
    {
        queries.Add(_dbContext.Makeups.Where(c => makeupIds.Contains(c.Id)).Select(c => new CombinedResult { Makeup = c }));
    }

    if (hairIds.Length > 0)
    {
        queries.Add(_dbContext.Hairs.Where(c => hairIds.Contains(c.Id)).Select(c => new CombinedResult { Hair = c }));
    }

    var clothes = new List<ClothesDbModel>();
    var makeups = new List<MakeupDbModel>();
    var hairs = new List<HairDbModel>();

    if (queries.Count > 0)
    {
        var query = queries[0];
        for (var i = 1; i < queries.Count; i++)
        {
            query = query.Concat(queries[i]);
        }

        var items = await query.ToListAsync();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item.Clothes != null)
                clothes.Add(item.Clothes);
            else if (item.Makeup != null)
                makeups.Add(item.Makeup);
            else if (item.Hair != null)
                hairs.Add(item.Hair);
        }
    }

    return (clothes.ToArray(), makeups.ToArray(), hairs.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: I got the following exception `Unable to translate set operation when both sides don't assign values to same properties in the nominal type. Please make sure that the properties are inclued on both sides, consider assigning default value if the property doesn't require a specific value.` So, I initialized the missing properties of CombinedResult with nulls. However, after that, I had another exception which is probably can be fixed `Unable to translate set operation after client projection has been applied. Consider moving the set operation before the last 'Select' call.`

Comment: Good to know, So forget about EF and normal `Concat` queries. Anyway this extension will run such query: https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore